# Wrong $http Get Method being called

Tags: c#, angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to use the $http.get method to retrieve a record. Instead of my Get method that accepts a parameter getting called, my empty Get method is called. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it so the correct Get method gets called?

RegistrationController

```
// Empty method that gets hit
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    return response;
}

// How do I structure my $http.get to have this method called?
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int pilotId)
{
    PilotModel pilot = this.RetrievePilot(pilotId);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    // If returnValue is null, the email or password was incorrect.
    if (pilot != null)
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse<PilotModel>(HttpStatusCode.Created, pilot);
    }
    else
    {
        response = Request.CreateResponse<PilotModel>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, pilot);
    }

    return response;
}
```

Front End (Extra code removed not needed to show problem...I believe)

```
var app = angular.module('MyRegistrationApp', []);

app.controller('RegistrationController', function ($scope, $http) {
    initializeVariables();

    var loggedInUser = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem('LoggedInUser'));

    if (loggedInUser !== null && loggedInUser.PilotId > 0) {

        // Shouldn't this url cause the Get with parametes to be called?
        var url = 'api/registration/' + loggedInUser.PilotId;

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url,
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                initializeVariables(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                alert(response.statusText);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a routing issue.  My advice is to use attribute routing, which allows you to be more precise about the actions that get picked up by a specific route.

Comment: Also can't use JSON.parse when sessionStorage doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks, I will try attribute routing. @charlietfl, thanks for the JSON.parse catch. I will fix that.

Comment: If you meant to decorate the method with [HttpGet], I tried that with no change in behavior. Can you provide an example?

Comment: What is the URL after $http runs? Can you post that here? Also, post your code that defines the routes, to see if there's any problem there.

Comment: The URL is http://localhost:9631/Registration. I use the default routeconfig.cs created by Visual Studio and have not modified it. I just put everything in the correct folder structure so it can be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you intended to make a GET call to this

```
http://my-api-url/api/registration/1
```

But in fact, your controller is expecting this:

```
http://my-api-url/api/registration?pilotId=1
```

Just try changing your `url` variable to the example below and you'll see it goes to the right action.

```
var url = 'api/registration?pilotId=' + loggedInUser.PilotId;
```

This happens because in **GET** requests parameters are sent as a query string. If you are okay with this, just change your `url` to the code above and you are good to go. If not, then a little of tweaking in your API is needed, but don't be scared.

**RegistrationController:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class RegistrationController : ApiController
{
    [Route("registration")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        return response;
    }

    [Route("registration/{pilotId:int}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int pilotId)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        //Your code goes here...
        return response;
    }
}
```

With these modifications in your RegistrationController, your existing code will work as expected. Basically all the "magic" is the `Route` attribute which provides you more control over the URL's in your API.

This particular Route:

```
[Route("registration/{pilotId:int}")]
```

Is creating a URL that is composed of "api/{controller}/" followed by a parameter of type `int` defined in a constraint `{pilotId:int}`. With this constraint, we force that the parameter passed after "registration" must be an int.

I encourage you to check this tutorial on [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), which is very helpful.

Comment: Got it. It works. Thank you for the detailed explanation and the link.